# WPF: Wire a Property Change to an Animation?

Tags: wpf, triggers, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF and have a View Model with a `DateTime` property. I already implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and auto-update my view with properties contained in the view model. I want to wire the `DateTime` property to a simple animation. How would I trigger an animation when the `DateTime` value changes?

Comment: Check out this answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21985212/512365 The one linked as duplicate is asking something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a Style in the XAML for the object displaying the property that has a DataTrigger for the property changing with a Storyboard(see here: [WPF MVVM Property Change Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649828/wpf-mvvm-property-change-animation))